# what does artman only specify retry settings for one interface in gapic yaml?

Tags: grpc

[image]

Regarding Artman, the configuration YAML file defines the configuration specifications. However, it does not provide an option to define global retry settings for each interface. The value named in the "interfaces" field must match a specific field name in the gRPC service.

Comment: how can i add global config for retry policy?

Comment: This is the official GitHub address. 
https://github.com/googleapis/gapic-generator/blob/master/src/main/proto/com/google/api/codegen/config.proto